# Tool or compilerflag to report missing cases in a switch statement

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, static-analysis

Is there a tool or a compiler flag to help identify switch statements missing one or more case statements?

The idea is

```
enum Colors { Black, Blue }
```

and

```
Colors c = Colors.Black;
```

then a number of places in the code I have

```
switch(c)
{
   case Black: 
     ... 
     break;
   case Blue: 
     ... 
     break;
}
```

When extending the colors enum, I need to visit all my switch statements and extend.

I know that possibly I could refactor the code to using strategies instead, but this was just an exaple.

I am also aware that had I implemented my switch as

```
switch(c)
{
   case Black: 
     ... 
     break;
   case Blue: 
     ... 
     break;
   default: throw new Exception("not supported " + c);
}
```

that I may have run out of luck.